# Can I use a $scope variable as a div background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to set a div `background-image` via AngularJS $scope variable.
This is what I have:

```
$scope.destination1 = 'web/images/' + obj.FirstPerson + '.png';
```

Then in the markup, I have this:

```
<div style="background-image:url(destination1)"  class="destination"></div>
```

I'm learning AngularJS at this time, so pardon if this looks dumb to those familiar with how AngularJS works. Can we do something like this?

### Update

Following the first reply, I did the changes and now the div looks like this:

```
<div id="destination" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{destination1}})'}"  class="destination"></div>
```

That is translated to this in the browser:
http://i.gyazo.com/e9e08f738d8ea52ed1ca5e0338692f65.png

As you can see the background-image property comes from nowhere with no value assigned, although the ng-class property is populated correctly.
Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax for ng-style is:

```
 <div ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{re.url}})'}" ></div>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7194/

also You can use custom directive :

```
app.directive('backgroundImageDirective', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + attrs.backgroundImageDirective + ')',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        });
    };
});
```

for example :

```
<div ng-repeat="re in recipes">
<div background-image-directive="{{re.url}}" style="height: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7193/

dont forget :

```
<div ng-style="'{{re.url}}' != '' && {'background-image':'url({{re.url}})'}" style="height: 100px"></div>
```

**update :**

```
<div ng-controller="UserController" ng-app="myApp">
           <div ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{destination1}})'}" style="height: 100px"></div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("UserController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.destination1="http://scalabilitysolved.com/content/images/2014/May/stackoverflow.png";
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7927/

Comment: Hello, thanks. instead of re.url, can I use my $scope.destination1 variable?

Comment: you use {{destination1}}

Comment: @user3763877 please check the update question I did in my initial content, thanks